# Popup Div location on page in gridview

Tags: javascript, css

I have a gridview with a link in each datarow. When user clicks the link, there is a popup div. The popup div is at a certain location on the page, but if there are a lot of rows in the gridview, user clicks on a link after scrolling down to the bottom of the page, the div pops up at the top of the page, moving the page back up to the top.

I would like the div to position on the page relative to where the link they click is. So, if they scroll down and click on gridview link, the div pops up down there. If a link at top of gridview, then popup there at top.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function CopyRecords() {            
            document.all.CopyItemsDiv.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("outerdiv2").style.display = 'block';                
        }
        function closeFrame2() {
            document.getElementById("outerdiv2").style.display = 'none';               
            location.replace('default.aspx');
        }    
    </script>

<div id="outerdiv2" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 550px; filter: alpha(opacity=85); z-index: 1001; display: none; background-color: white; border: .125em solid #736F6E;">
    <div style="text-align: right; padding: .25em .5em; font-size: 1.25em; border: outset 2px gray; margin-bottom: 4px; background-color: #cccccc;">
    <span style="float: left; font-size: medium;">Import Budget</span>
            <b><a href="javascript:closeFrame2();" style="cursor: pointer; color: Black;" title="close window">&#120;</a></b></div>
                <div  id="CopyItemsDiv" style="height: 150px; width: 300px; border: none; margin-left: 15px;" >

                    Div Contents... 
                </div>               
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your example is incomplete: http://jsfiddle.net/6H7Ss/5/embedded/result/ There is nothing shown on the screen.

Please update the code for a more complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/6H7Ss/

Then I'll try to answer.

Comment: Im not sure that i understand. It works fine on my website. Div is invisible, then the javascript sets it to visible or "block" when I click button <asp:hyperlink id="import" runat="server" onclick="CopyRecords();" Font-Size="X-Small" Text="Import budget"></asp:hyperlink>

Comment: So you wont help because it doesn't work on jsfiddle? Is there some other way to figure this thing out? The javascript fires up just fine on my website, but not on jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry - it's not like I won't help. It's like the problem isn't clear to me. :)

Comment: My issue is that I don't see the beahviour how you describe it, so I can't picture what you're after - since your code is ASP specific, not generic HTML/JavaScrip/CSS.